# call stack from Docker shows my local paths. Is it nomal?

Tags: linux, docker

I created a .NET Core controller returning pdf file which works fine on my local machine. When I wrap it into a Linux image I receive an error: 
*The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.* 
So I created a logging tool which gave me that call stack:

> *at
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipNewPrivateFontCollection(IntPtr&
>   fontCollection)
>  at SelectPdf.Lib.ᡜ..ctor()
>  at
>   SelectPdf.Lib.៞..ctor()
>     at SelectPdf.Lib.៞..ctor(ᡏ A_0, ᠝
>   A_1)
>     at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ᜁ(String A_0, String A_1, String
>   A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4)
>     at
>   SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(String htmlString)
>     at
>   PdfBuilders.PdfBuilder.Create() in
>   C:\Projects\server\intranet.api\Intranet.Api\PDFCreators\PdfBuilder.cs:line
>   65
>  at
>   WorklogAgregators.SingleEmployeePdfReport.CreateReport(PhotoLoginReportWithTotalDto
>   reportDto, String& fileName) in
>   C:\Projects\server\intranet.api\Intranet.Api\WorklogAgregators\SingleEmployeePdfReport.cs:line
>   58
>  at
>   Login.Api.Controllers.WorklogTimesController.d__10.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Projects\server\intranet.api\Intranet.Api\Login.API\Controllers\WorklogTimesController.cs:line
>   138*

And here is the funny part: 
Path *C:\Projects\server\intranet.api* is where I keep the code on my local machine, but docker image has been put onto external server. 
Is there some possibility that docker image actually searches for those files and that is the reason why it does not work?
Every other controllers works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR** You've built your app on your local PC together with `pdb` files and these files store your local paths, which are displayed regardless of where the code is being executed.

Error reporting as well as debug info recovers data from so-called `pdb` files, which are program database. These files store meta information about your program code, including original file names, locations and source code line numbers. 
The amount of information stored is controllable and usually depends on your build type (`Debug`, `Release`). These files are being distributed together with your binaries and whichever system is used as a host, whenever it needs meta information (like call stack), it takes it from them.